# Cross-Compiling to ARM target hardware: getting errors : aarch64-linux-gnu-g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-msse4.2’

Tags: cross-compiling, embedded-linux, yocto

> aarch64-linux-gnu-g++: error: unrecognized command line option
>   ‘-msse4.2’ aarch64-linux-gnu-g++: error: unrecognized command line
>   option ‘-mfpmath=sse’

How to solve this? Regarding cross compiling to ARM

Comment: Did you check what options does aarch64-linux-gnu-g++ support?

Answer (score 0):

Something is telling the build to use `-msse4.2` which is Intel-specific.  You'll need to provide far more details: what recipe, what BSP, etc.